# How can I use Data from my app to be displayed in Widget SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

I'm working on an app that lets me store information about my upcoming homework. I have a Core Data Entity for my homework called "Hausaufgabe". Now I want to display the count of my Homework in a Widget. When I use:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Hausaufgabe.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor()]) var hausaufgaben : FetchedResults<Hausaufgabe>
```

and then

```
Text("\(hausaufgaben.count)")
```

It works on all the views inside my app and displays the correct number. But when I use the same code in the WidgetEntryView, It just displays 0, regardless of how many homework are in the list.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Put your CoreData store in an app group. But something to know this still requires a timeline reload when there is a change.

Comment: [how to setup store url](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit), get [appgroup url](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/core-data-app-extension-data-sharing/)

Comment: thanks for the hint, but how do I do a timeline reload?

Comment: Look at the [Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie) you load your core data objects in the getTimeline method. SwiftUI code doesn’t work like main app SwiftUI there is no listening. The wrappers will not refresh views